# Can you have multiple one to many relationships to same table id in HIBERNATE?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

So I am trying to implement this using Hibernate:
[image: Database Schema]

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer_id")
    private List<CustomerAddress> shippingAddresses;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer_id")
    private List<CustomerAddress> billingAddresses;

    // some other stuff that isn't relevant to the problem
}
```

This is the customer address entity and the confusion is to determine whether an address is for billing or shipping? Is there a way to use isBilling or isShipping? I could do this at the repository layer with just one (one to many) mapping within Customer for addresses but I would prefer to do it with Hibernate if possible.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer_Address")
public class CustomerAddress extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    // some other stuff that isn't relevant to the problem
}
```

Comment: Suggest that you go back to documentation and read about "mappedBy". It points to a FIELD not a COLUMN. And to answer your question, NO, that mapping cannot work because to populate one of the Lists it looks in the FK column and doesnt know which collection to use.

Comment: Thank you Neil, I will be sure to read the docs